# Chatter Library for Angular.js/ Ionic for hybrid mobile app

Tags: mobilesdk, hybrid, angular

I want to know if there is any open source library using Angular.js that i can use in my hybrid app for integrating Chatter functionality. From what I have seen so far, ngForce is not suitable for use with hybrid apps and is good only for VF page integration. There's nforce but it's not written in Angular.js

I'm contemplating building a hybrid app using Angular.js or Ionic - any quick guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably no open source Ionic or Angular library available for now for hybrid apps specifically for Chatter API. You should look at [forceng](https://github.com/ccoenraets/forceng) though. Since Chatter operations are handled by [Chatter REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/), it's really all about hitting those endpoints using your Angular/ ionic code using forcetk from your hybrid app.

There's another library [JSForce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#chatter-api) which you can look at for reference purposes but it's not written in Angular or Ionic.